# Django admin add own wms layer

Tags: django-admin, openlayers, wms

I know how to display a base layer map in django admin, openlayers or osm.
I would like to display also my own wms layer.
I went in my .../dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin to find options.py and in .../dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/templates/gis/admin to find the openlayers.js.
I manage to replace the basic layer with my wms layer but not both at the time.
Any idea how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: You've found the gis admin templates, and you can override them in your app. What do you mean with "but not both at the time"?